# Performance Issue - 2009 Infinity FX50

Tags: performance, rpm, infiniti

Please, I need help. My care is shaking and this code is appear in comp test  p0021 int/v tim cont-b2   1t
Please ..i clean the intake valve control timing on both side then after that this code appear p0011 and p0524 of ather side [image]

[image]

And b2 we see the selenoid vale was damage and i change it and intake valve control timing was blocked by dirty oil we cleaned it befor this code appear

Comment: Is the car making any sounds when it's not running well? Is it slow in speed or slow in acceleration/power?

Comment: The car on P position is same problem when i increase gasoline acceleration the care rpm not increase over 3500 and 5000 like choking and this two cod appear on computer test

Comment: The code appear 1.engine oil pressure 2. Vtc intake side .valve control system b2

Comment: So sory of my bad words i live in kurdistan .iraq

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Cheers!

Comment: @tlhIngan  please can you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first why is it revving at 4k to do 120kmph? This is concerning and could mean the car is in some sort of limp mode or you are in the wrong gear. most likely its wrong gear since there is no check engine light on. or I am not properly understanding what is meant by "4000 rpm and 120 km will run slow"

or do you have a manual transmission or an automatic transmission? I think it may be slipping.

If it is a manual then your clutch may be worn out and no longer gripping

if its an automatic than one or more bands may be worn out and no longer gripping.

either way you do not want to let the engine suddenly speed up without the car also speeding up proportionally as this will cause rapid wear of whichever part is slipping.

Let me know if you have a manual or automatic transmission and I can give you some stuff to look for.

---

ok that tells me it's not the trans slipping it is simply the engines performance not letting the car go faster.

First lets address the oil issue.

- Do you have the right amount of oil in the car?
- have you changed the oil relatively regularly
- is the oil that is in there now the correct weight
- how many miles on the car and can you tell the oil pressure is there a gauge on the dash that shows you have acceptable oil pressure?

the other code

this has to do with your variable valve timing and could be why you cant rev the engine past about 4k. If it is stuck in low rpm mode then you might be able to get up to a speed but not past it simply due to a lack of power at higher RPMs. This also fits in the solenoid that moves the cam around is sticking so sometimes the variable valve timing does work and gives you more power.

I would really look into the oil issue first before the variable valve timing problem. when you do dig into the variable valve timing I bet it will be a sticky or worn out solenoid.

Also your english is pretty good. :)

---

That is good advice. You don't need to change the oil every 3k unless you are somewhere that is dusty or drive the vehicle hard or the oil that is being used is low grade but low grade does not sound like what you are using. Safe bet is change religiously at 5k or a bit sooner.

In this particular case you may want to change sooner even at a few hundred miles to 1000 as the new oil can dislodge built up gunk.

your oil pressure error code is still something to be concerned about.

And you are welcome! :)

---

that would be the oil sensor. definitely want to address this as a first thing. low oil pressure means the engine will not last long. and if the cams work using hydraulics to move them back and forth then this could solve the low speed issue too. They can use hydraulic pressure in other ways to create variable valve lift and timing and if you have low pressure it can affect these other ways too.

My guess is you need to replace your oil pump it may be worn out. If you are lucky it could be a plugged up oil pressure sensor. You might want to start there first. Pull the sensor and see if it is caked over with crud.

---

That is good news! [here is some instructions for servicing the variable timing solenoid](http://my.prostreetonline.com/2014/07/31/dtc-p1145-how-to-service-your-vtc-solenoid-valve/). you may be able to simply clean it with some electric contact cleaner. also look for plugged ports. let me know what they find with the VCT solenoid.

---

[here is some more information on that code](http://automecanico.com/auto2043/IVTCVQ35DE.pdf)

here are some pertinent excerpts from it

> Component Inspection EBS00D4K
>  INTAKE VALVE TIMING CONTROL
>   SOLENOID VALVE
>   1. Disconnect intake valve timing control solenoid valve harness connector.
>   2. Check resistance between intake valve timing control solenoid valve terminals as follows
>
> Terminals ----------------- Resistance
>  1 and 2
>   ------------------- 7.0 - 7.5Ω at 20°C (68°F)
>  1 or 2 and ground ------ ∞Ω
>   ------------------------------ (Continuity should not exist)
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

[This is the previous page](http://automecanico.com/auto2043/) and may have more manuals but some look to be in other languages

Comment: I was on automatic transmition D when i stop the car and put transmision on P thers ssme problem the rpm not go over 3500 or 4000 and 2 cods appear on computer test .1.engine oil presure ..2..vtc intake side valve control system b2 ..

Comment: Sory of my bad words i live in kurdistan .iraqs

Comment: @Mohamadomer take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so muche .when i change the oil the michanic told me that my cars oil is very dirty its not change the owner not chane it i put synethetic oil but not good brand he told to me that i shoul change oil for short time to clean the ingine

Comment: @Mohamadomer more edits to my answer. and you're welcome!

Comment: Hi dear cc dr  this morning the check ingine light begin on and i test the car by obd2 the result was p0524 engine oil presure too low the oil sensor make this code?or the oil pump ?

Comment: @Mohamadomer updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much i change the two oil sensor the problem is gon after 4 hours nothing happing the care now good the micanic told me that the sensor oil was changed but was a fuke beand not readin all oil or was bad ..thank you for your help i glad to servise you when you come to iraq .kurdistan

Comment: @Mohamadomer You are welcome :) also I edited my answer with some info on replacing the variable timing valves for the other issue you are having. You may be able to clean and reuse the solenoids but also check for blockages in the oil passages.

Comment: Before sensore code appeared  i change the 2 selenoid valve b2 one of them was damaged and not work and the other was worked but slow and blocked  i will change both of them with new

Comment: @Mohamadomer if you already replaced one its probably still good and doesn't need replacing again but it might need cleaning. also the other one if it works great but if it's plugged then not so great. You should be able to test them by giving them power but not sure if they just take 12v or if they need something else from the computer.

Comment: After changine both sensor i drive the care hard drive and i return to michanic then he test my car by computer show no cod and problem ..is that mean my issue is disappear

Comment: @Mohamadomer and it no longer goes slow?

Comment: p0021 int/v tim cont-b2  ined help this codes appear my car shaking

Comment: @Mohamadomer the code showed up again?

Comment: Yes the code show again

Comment: @Mohamadomer so both of the cam advanced solenoids have been replaced? and there isn't any blockages?

Comment: @Mohamadomer int/v tim cont-b2 did you change or clean up and tested the timing solenoid for the intake cam on bank 2 of that engine? Bank 2 is usually where piston 2 is located but check your shop manual for that engine.

Comment: @Mohamadomer big edit with more information on the code.

Comment: Thañx very much .my michanic said that shoud clean the variable valve timing because the oil transmision to seliniod valve may blocked in this area that make the selinoid valve not work good ..is that true idia ?

Comment: @Mohamadomer yes if it is blocked it definitely will not work as it cannot get any oil pressure to move the cam around.